# Angular child component is updating, but view is not until click anywhere

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

Child component updating. But it appears when i click anywhere on the window.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
selectedId: string
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<div>
  <child-component [id]="selectedId"></child-component>
</div>
```

Child component does what it is supposed to do. but i see updated view when i click second time (first click is for open the popup and send the new selectedId to child). It shows with previous Id until click.
How can refresh the view?

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input()
  selectedId: string;

comments: Comments[];

 ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.selectedId) {
      this.commentService
        .getCommentsById(this.selectedId)
        .subscribe(comments => {
          this.comments = comments;
          this.comments.reverse();
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you create demo stackblitz?

Comment: Please post the code of your child component

Comment: thank you, posted on my first message

Comment: Did you set the component change detection strategy to `OnPush`?

Comment: No, i do not know how i set that actually.

Comment: @mark which version of angular are you using?

Comment: You are sending id but in child writing invoiceId. They aren't match. and selectedId in ngOnChanges() what is selectedId?

Answer (score 0):

In the `ngOnChanges()` function, you need to take the `changes: SimpleChanges` argument as input as below.

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.selectedId.currentValue) {
    this.loadComments(changes.selectedId.currentValue);
  }
}

loadComments(id) {
  this.commentService.getCommentsById(id).subscribe(comments => {
    this.comments = comments;
    this.comments.reverse();
  });
}
```

Along with this, add `async` pipe where ever you are using the `comments` like this `{{ comments | async }}`

This will load the component promptly with the updated data always.